# I upload videos into into directory and i want them to display horizontall when i echo them

Tags: php

I have these codes and am not good at php please can someone help me on how to echo the videos to appear horizontall in my page thanks in advance

```
<?php
$h=2;
$k=mysql_query("SELECT * from aupload where type='audios' and view>='$h' order by view DESC");

while ($la=mysql_fetch_array($k)){

?> 

<center>
<table width='100%'height=''>
<tr>
<?php echo"<td>" . "<a href='uploads/$la[filename]'><img src='uploads/$la[size]' width='180px' height='180px'>
<br><b>$la[filename]</b><br><a href='music1.php?id=".$la['id']."'><input type='button' value='DOWNLOAD'><input type='button' value='$la[view]'>     </a></a>
"?></td>
</tr>
</table><br>
</center>
<?php }?>  

<?php
include('connect.php');

$k=mysql_query("SELECT * from aupload where type='audios'");
@$la=mysql_fetch_array($k)
?>



<?php
$h=2;
$y=mysql_query("SELECT * from aupload where type='videos' and view>='$h' order by view DESC ");

?>
<table border='0' id='myTable'width='100%'>

<?php
while ($x=mysql_fetch_array($y)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<video id='myVideo' onclick='message()' width='180px'  height='180px' controls><source src='uploads/$x[filename]' '></video>" .   "</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";


echo "<tr>";
echo  "<td width='' height=''>"."<a href='music2.php?id=$x[id]' >   <b>$x[filename]</b><br><input type='button' value='DOWNLOAD'></a>" ."<input  type='button' value='$x[view]'></a></a>". "</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>"; echo"</center>";

?>
```

the problem is when I upload two or more videos they appear vertically but I just want them to appear horizontally when echo them please someone help and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use frames is the best way to display a video, try this code

Comment: what codes? unfortunatelly i dnt know how to use frame can you help

Comment: Instead of table use iframes

Comment: Instead of table use iframes example <iframe src="url" width="200" height="200"></iframe>,if you want more details then search iframe in google you will get all details you needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a HTML question, not a PHP question. In HTML,  designates a table row, and can contain many  or table cell elements. So you want to have the a  echoed before the while loop, then print just the  elements in the while loop, then print the . This will put all the elements in a single table row.

Comment: thanks alot Its like I understand your concept but I cant put it into implementation can you be kind enough to put into into codes please?